# Bind ListView in ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, listview, binding, xamarin.forms, controltemplate

I have a ControlTemplate in my App.xaml like bellow:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTempplate">
    <ListView x:Name="MyListView"
        AutomationId="SelectRelationListViewId"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyListViewData}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}"
        BackgroundColor="White" 
        RowHeight="60" 
        SeparatorColor="White" 
        IsGroupingEnabled="False" 
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="#E7E4E0" 
                          Padding="20,0,20,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" 
                                   Text="{Binding MyName}" 
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ControlTemplate>
```

My page is bound with my ViewModel and if I copy/paste the code from my template to my pagem, data and events are correctly handled but nothing happend when I try to use my template, the ListView is empty and the events are not triggered.

I already tried "{TemplateBinding DataContext.MyPropertyNameToBind}".

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it doesn't work either

Comment: If it `Xamarin.Forms` you should use `{TemplateBinding BindingContext.MyPropertyNameToBind}` instead of `DataContext`

Answer (score 0):

We need more details on your code and your intention on creating a control template but here are the steps that can help you:

### 1- First: ControlTemplate utility,

in Xamarin Forms, a 'ControlTemplate' is used to customize appearance of a control. More precisely it defines the layout in which the content will be displayed.

- So it should contain a 'ContentPresenter' object.
- It can be applied only on 'ContentPage' and 'ContentView' objects

--> On which UI 'Element' are you trying to bind your ControlTemplate to ?

### 2- Then using TemplateBindings (I suspect a problem here)

If I'm right, TemplateBindings can only be used to bind to 'Parent' **Bindable Properties**.

When you are doing:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
   <ListView ItemsSource={TemplateBinding BindingContext} />
...
```

**It's ok** because 'BindingContext' is a BindableProperty, but if you do:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
   <ListView ItemsSource={TemplateBinding BindingContext.MyItems} />
...
```

**It's ko** because 'BindingContext.MyItems' is not a BindableProperty (I presume)

### 3- Finally, what to do ?

**Solution 1**

Create in your page that owns the templated control, intermediate **BindableProperties** that bind to your ViewModel.

Then your 'TemplateBindings' should reference these properties.

A good example using 'TemplateBinding' & 'BindableProperty' here:
[Xamarin TemplateBinding documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/template-binding/).

**Solution 2**

For me, I will prefer to extract to App.xaml,

- the ListView DataTemplate to a new data template resource
- the Listview properties into a new 'ListView' Style

And in my page I would have:

```
<Page ...>
   <ListView x:Name="myList"
         Style="{StaticResource MyListViewStyle}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding vmItems}"
         DataTemplate="{StaticResource MyListViewDataTemplate}"
         />
```

In fact you can include the 'DataTemplate' property inside your Style directly...

Let me know if it helps.